# Parsing an integer with nom always results in Incomplete

Tags: rust, nom

Everything I try gives me `Incomplete(Size(1))`. My best guess right now is:

```
named!(my_u64(&str) -> u64,
    map_res!(recognize!(nom::digit), u64::from_str)
);
```

Test:

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod test {
    #[test]
    fn my_u64() {
        assert_eq!(Ok(("", 0)), super::my_u64("0"));
    }
}
```

Sometimes in my variations (e.g. adding `complete!`) I've been able to get it to parse if I add a character onto the end.

I'd like to get a working parse for this (ultimately my hope is that this will allow me to create a parser for a `u64` wrapper type) but bigger picture I'd like to get a grasp of how to build a parser properly myself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nom 4 made the handling of partial data much stricter than in previous versions, to better support streaming parsers and custom input types.

Effectively, if the parser runs out of input and it can't tell that it's *meant* to have run out of input, it'll always return `Err::Incomplete`. This may also contain information on exactly how much more input the parser was expecting (in your case, at least 1 more byte).

It determines whether there's potentially any more input using the [`AtEof`](https://docs.rs/nom/4.0.0/nom/trait.AtEof.html) trait. This always returns `false` for `&str` and `&[u8]`, as they don't provide any information about whether they're complete or not!

The trick is to change the input type of your parsers to make it explicit that the input will always be complete - Nom provides the [`CompleteStr`](https://docs.rs/nom/4.0.0/nom/types/struct.CompleteStr.html) and [`CompleteByteSlice`](https://docs.rs/nom/4.0.0/nom/types/struct.CompleteByteSlice.html) wrappers for this purpose, or you can implement your own input type.

So in order for your parser to work as expected, it'd need to look something like this:

```
named!(my_u64(CompleteStr) -> u64,
    map_res!(recognize!(nom::digit), u64::from_str)
);
```

And your test would look something like this:

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod test {
    #[test]
    fn my_u64() {
        assert_eq!(Ok((CompleteStr(""), 0)), super::my_u64(CompleteStr("0")));
    }
}
```

See [the announcement post for Nom 4](http://unhandledexpression.com/general/2018/05/14/nom-4-0-faster-safer-simpler-parsers.html) for more details.

Comment: An aside - I'm not on a machine with a Rust compiler right now, so if the code examples are wrong, let me know and I'll fix them later :p

Comment: This is great, thank you. This is a really good explanation and I feel like I've progressed from throwing stuff at the wall to it sticks to actually having a handle on the behavior now.

Comment: @spease: No problem, I think writing this answer was the first time it fully clicked for me too :D

Comment: I get this error `expected &str, found struct nom::types::CompleteStr` any ideas why?

Comment: @Pumphouse a) Do your parsers have the correct signature? b) Are you wrapping your input strings in `CompleteStr` before trying to pass them in?

Comment: @Pumphouse Never mind, saw your separate question got an answer :)

Comment: Just to be sure... Is `recognize` taking the digits from the `CompleteStr` and returning a `&str` directly? The example in the other question needed to retrieve the inner value from `CompleteStr` explicitly.

Comment: You might be right (I didn't have nom installed when I wrote this answer) - will try to verify later.

Comment: I think those types are gone from nom 5.1.1 documentation, answer might required update

Answer (score 12):

As of `nom 5.1.1` approach towards combining parsers changed from macro-based to function based, what is discussed broader in [nom's author blog](http://unhandledexpression.com/general/2019/06/17/nom-5-is-here.html).

Along with this change another followed - *streaming* and *complete* parsers are now residing in different modules and you need to explicitly choose which type of parsing you need. Most usually there is a clear distinction with module name.

Old macros are preserved, but they work strictly in streaming mode. Types like `CompleteStr` or `CompleteByteSlice` are gone.

To write code you asked for *the new way* you could do it for example like this (**notice explicit `character::complete` in imports**)

*Since it took me some time to grasp it - parsers e.g `map_res` return a `impl Fn(I) -> IResult<I, O2, E>` which is why there is additional pair of parenthesis - to call that closure.*

```
use std::str;
use nom::{
    IResult,
    character::complete::{
        digit1
    },
    combinator::{
        recognize,
        map_res
    }
};

fn my_u64(input : &str) -> IResult<&str, u64> {
    map_res(recognize(digit1), str::parse)(input)
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod test {
    use super::*;
    #[test]
    fn test_my_u64() {
        let input = "42";
        let num = my_u64(input);
        assert_eq!(Ok(("", 42u64)), num);
    }
}
```