# Why does nom expect a &str when I pass a CompleteStr?

Tags: rust, nom

The parser works as expected until I want to parse the `h:` digit which is always the last digit in the string and the compiler gives me

```
^ expected &str, found struct `nom::types::CompleteStr`
```

I assume it's because the parser is looking ahead. How do I stop that, or how can I signify it's done?

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate nom;

use nom::digit;
use nom::types::CompleteStr;
use std::str::FromStr;

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
pub struct Order {
    pub l: u64,
    pub w: u64,
    pub h: u64,
}

named!(order_parser<CompleteStr, Order>,
    do_parse!(
        l: map_res!(digit, u64::from_str) >>
        tag!("x") >>
        w: map_res!(digit, u64::from_str) >>
        tag!("x") >>
        h: map_res!(digit, u64::from_str) >>
        (Order {l:  l, w: w, h: h })
    )
);

pub fn wrap_order(order: &str) -> Result<(CompleteStr, Order), nom::Err<&str>> {
    order_parser(order)
}

#[test]
fn test_order_parser() {
    assert_eq!(
        wrap_order(CompleteStr("2x3x4")),
        Ok((CompleteStr(""), Order { l: 2, w: 3, h: 4 }))
    );
}
```

Comment: I believe your question is answered by the answers of [Why does my nom parser not consume the entire input, leaving the last piece unparsed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52720072/155423) / [Parsing an integer with nom](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51257031/155423). If you disagree, please [edit] your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: I changed it as I read up and still can't seem to get it to work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is not on the last digit parser, it's on each of them (Rust 1.30.0 prints the error three times). That's because `u64::from_str` works on `&str`, not `CompleteStr`.

You can fix your parsers to use `u64::from_str` correctly this way:

```
do_parse!(
    l: map_res!(digit, |CompleteStr(s)| u64::from_str(s)) >>
    tag!("x") >>
    w: map_res!(digit, |CompleteStr(s)| u64::from_str(s)) >>
    tag!("x") >>
    h: map_res!(digit, |CompleteStr(s)| u64::from_str(s)) >>
    (Order { l: l, w: w, h: h })
)
```

There are also some unrelated error with the next function, which can be fixed by using the appropriate types in the signature:

```
pub fn wrap_order(order: &str) -> Result<(CompleteStr, Order), nom::Err<CompleteStr>> {
    order_parser(CompleteStr(order))
}
```